# What does the reduced palette option in Eclipse offer to user

Tags: eclipse, settings, color-scheme

I would like to know what does the reduced palette option in Eclipse offer to user.

(In Windows) `Window > Peferences > Appearance - Color and Font Theme`

What are the settings that it changes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Reduced Palette theme overrides the colors selected by the application and replace them with system colors. Reduced Palette is the default theme in High Contrast mode (on platforms where this is available). This is mainly an accessibility setting for people with poor vision.